# Tags should be links when pasting a question link to chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, chat

Try this:

- go to chat
- paste a link to trilogy question e.g  [Tags should be links when pasting a question link to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57071/tags-should-be-links-when-pasting-a-question-link-to-chat)
- hover the cursor around resulting image => question title is a link but tags are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer so this question can be removed from [Unanswered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) view.